# Starting a jar file from an OSX java app

Tags: java, macos, maven, jar, .app

I have created an application that is updated by another application. The updater is bundled into an OSX .app, and is meant to update anything in its resource directory. When the updater is started, it looks for updates, then runs `System.getRuntime().exec(cmd)`, where `cmd` is simply  the path to the bundled JRE followed by the application's jar.

If I run the updater jar file, everything works as expected. However, when I run the app, the updater starts normally, but when the "start" button is pressed, the application is not starting. In fact, nothing is happening. There are no errors at the command line levels, and no exceptions are thrown when creating the process. `process.isAlive()` returns true.

As I said, this works fine when launched from the jar updater file. The .app directory was made using the maven plugin "appbundle". The application is available at https://github.com/elyas145/lss-reporter. However you cannot launch it without the secret file for checking updates. Unfortunately I cannot post that online.

Answer (score 1):

It was a very dumb mistake. I was specifying the jar file I am trying to open in the exec call without specifying the directory. I forgot that the call is made from the root directory and not from the resource folder. so I needed to build the directory the jar file and pass that to the java command.